# Read compile error report format: format_io.c:3:10:

Tags: c

I compiled a program and get

```
format_io.c:3:6: error: cannot combine with previous 'void' declaration specifier
void int int int
     ^
format_io.c:3:10: error: cannot combine with previous 'void' declaration specifier
void int int int
         ^
```

how read `format_io.c:3:6:`,
when check line 6, do no t find the void error.

Comment: It means it cannot combine the `int` with a `void`, not the `void` with a previous undisplayed `void`. And `void int` is a colourless green declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*filename*:*line*:*column*

Column 6 of line 3. And column 10 of line 3.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I dispute that this answer would be better if it was longer. I considered leaving it at the first line!

Comment: (The question contains some bad English grammar, but I'm fairly certain it *is* asking how to interpret the numbers in the error message, and there is no actual doubt about the validity of `void int int int`)

Comment: The problem with your answer is 1) you are answering an off topic question which supplies no code. 2) You give no explanation of how this answers the question. It's just blurting words out with no meaning. That's not what SO is about.